# SE app doesn't support "refresh" for "hot questions" page

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Simple request - on the SE app, most pages refresh if pulled down. But "hot questions" doesn't have this action - you have to go *back* to your feed, pull *that* down to refresh it, and *then* click "hot questions" to see the refreshed H.Q's.

Can this be improved by allowing pulldown on H.Q's itself?

Comment: They stopped updating the Android app. So chances are, that this will never happen, unless more people start using it